# Gradient descent with polynomial features implementation issue

Tags: python, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

I am trying to implement gradient descent after transforming some random data using sklearns polynomial transformer. My code works when not using polynomial features, but gives really high coefficients when transforming.

Is there an issue with my code (below)?

```
    l= 20

    np.random.seed(0)
    X = 2 - 3 * np.random.normal(0, 1, l)
    y = X - 2 * (X ** 2) + 0.5 * (X ** 3) + np.random.normal(-3, 3, l)
    plt.scatter(X,y, s=10)
    plt.show()

    X = X.reshape(-1,1)

    m, n = X.shape

    p = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

    xbp = p.fit_transform(X)

    # initiate coefs
    theta = np.ones((xbp.shape[1], 1))

    for _ in range(500):
        err = xbp.dot(theta) - y.reshape(-1, 1)
        gradients = 2 / m * xbp.T.dot(err)
        theta -= 0.01 * gradients

    print(theta)
    print()
    print(LinearRegression().fit(xbp, y).coef_)
```

output

```
     [[  802.60118234]
     [  360.65857329]
     [12234.00939771]]

    [ 0.          8.48492679 -1.62853134]
```

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOlzv.png)

Thanks

Comment: did you try to draw it ? Maybe it gives correct values. Values ` 0.          8.48492679 -1.62853134` are small.

Comment: BTW: I found the same image in article [Polynomial Regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/polynomial-regression-bbe8b9d97491)

Comment: Yes thats the article i got the inputs from, but its my implementation of gradient descent that gets it wrong somewhere, as it is completely different from the sklearn LinearRegression coefficients

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see values inside loop and compare it with calculations on paper.

Comment: i have already tried breaking down the components, i feel like i am missing somethng that is needed when handling polynomials

Comment: @furas do you have no solution for this? still not figured it out.